# Can't open OpenJDK java 7 runtime

Tags: java

I installed OpenJDK java 7 runtime through the software centre.
When I go to search for it, all I find is 'OpenJKD java 7 policy tool'.
I can't find anything online about how to handle the policy tool.

Answer (score 0):

The Java runtime has no graphical frontend.

Show the java version with:

```
java -version
```

or run a jar file (java archive)

```
java -jar <your_jar_file>
```

---

For OpenJDK7, a desktop file doesn't exist by default.

To start a java application (jar), via double-click or context menu in your file manager, you could create a `desktop` file for OpenJDK7:

1. Create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications/`

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/openjdk7.desktop
   ```
2. Add the lines below:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Open JDK 7 Runtime
   Comment=Open JDK 7 Runtime
   Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar %f
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=java
   MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
3. Replace the line:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar %f
   ```

   with the location of your java installation. You can check the installed JREs with:

   ```
   update-alternatives --display java
   ```

   Sample output:

   ```
   java - auto mode
     link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
     slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
     slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1083
     slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java - priority 1084
   Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java'.
   ```

---

Policy tool

The last security-related tool that comes with the Java platform is policytool. This tool allows you to manage entries in a java.policy file. Unlike the other tools we've discussed, policytool is a graphical tool. As such, it has no command-line options or arguments.

When you first start policytool, you see a blank window with two pull-down menus: <kbd>File</kbd> and <kbd>Edit</kbd>. Initially, there are no policy entries loaded into this tool; if you want to work on an existing policy file, the first thing you must do is choose the Open command from the File menu. Otherwise, you can add new entries and create a new file containing those entries. Whichever method you choose, keep in mind that policytool is designed to operate on a single policy file.

When you've completed editing the entries for a policy file, you can save your changes. Under the File menu, you can use the Save or Save As command to overwrite the file you loaded or to save your changes to a new file.

<sub>[Source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/appa_03.htm)</sub>